# set findstr to variable to reference

Tags: batch-file

So essentially, I want to set the output of findstr to a variable, and to test for this in an if statement to see if it picked it up or not. I have tried both reading the output directly and reading a text file, but it has occurred to me that that isn't the problem.
Here is the batch file.

```
cd C:\
cd "Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16"
@Echo on
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
@Echo off
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus > C:\ospp.txt
Echo ========Output Saved to C:\ospp.txt=========
PAUSE
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
REM set /p input="Please type the 5 digit office key: "
CALL for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir ^| findstr /c:12345 ') do set input=%%a
IF [%input%] == [] GOTO EXIT
IF [%input%] == [12345] GOTO 12345
IF [%input%] == [54321] GOTO 54321
REM cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:%input%
echo Key would be removed.
PAUSE
GOTO:eof
:EXIT
    Echo Insufficiant parameters.
    PAUSE
    GOTO:eof
:12345
    echo Key ending in "12345" already active
    PAUSE
    GOTO:eof
:54321
    echo Key ending in "54321" already active
    PAUSE
    GOTO:eof
```

I have set 12345 and 54321 as test variables. This batch file is supposed to remove office keys that aren't supposed to be there, so I've removed the actual key characters for the sake of asking this question.
I don't know if this will work without office installed.
Output that I don't want is

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

---Processing--------------------------
---------------------------------------
PRODUCT ID: 00339-23800-39315-AA300
SKU ID: c47456e3-265d-47b6-8ca0-c30abbd0ca36
LICENSE NAME: Office 16, Office16ProPlusVL_MAK edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 16, RETAIL(MAK) channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED---
Last 5 characters of installed product key: 12345
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---Exiting-----------------------------
========Output Saved to C:\ospp.txt=========
Press any key to continue . . .
Key would be removed.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `CALL FOR ...` can't work, it's only `FOR ...`. And `findstr /c:12345` will never find `54321`

Comment: I know it won't check for 54321, I'm only checking for one at the moment, and once that's working I'll check for the other. And I'm using call so that it doesn't close the window immediately when that line fails.
Edit: well after removing call, it no longer closes but always results in "key will be removed" even on my live build with the actual key in place of 12345

Comment: If findstr doesn't find anything, the part `set input=%%a` will never be executed, `input` has still the content it had before you started your batch. Better use `set "input="` before the loop

Comment: so setting it to nothing at the beginning of the live build, it still fails hitting would be deleted, so it's set to something that isn't the key. any idea what that  would be?

Comment: `'dir ^| findstr /c:12345 '` doesn't look right.  The output of `dir` at the root of your system drive, may in fact have that sequence in it, have you looked?  Why `dir`?  Shouldn't you be reading a file?

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `findstr /?` and read the output help. __FINDSTR__ never outputs just the found occurrence of a search string, but always the entire line containing a found string or the lines not containing a searched string on using `/V` (inVers output). I recommend to run next `for /?` and read the output help carefully from top of first page to bottom of last page to understand the command line:

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe "%~dp0ospp.vbs" /dstatus 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Last 5 characters of installed product key" set /A Key=%%J`

Comment: However, I would strongly recommend __not__ using a VBScript executed by console version of Windows Script Host `cscript.exe` executed from a batch file executed by Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe`. That does not make sense. The VBScript can be written to get just the last five numbers of product key and evaluate it. The user input could be done with VBScript better and more secure than with batch. The VBScript would be also for the user much more comfortable on using Windows GUI version `wscript.exe` prompting the user for the number in a graphical window.

Comment: It looks like it does not make much difference to ask for help on a VBScript only solution for your task on Stack Overflow as your knowledge on writing a batch file is not greatly better than on writing a VBScript file. See [SS64](https://ss64.com/) for help on batch file or VBScript file writing.

Comment: So i haven't the slightest clue on how to make a vb script, what syntax it uses or what it even is. and SS64 has both unix bash stuff and windows, and everyone refers to it as the same thing but there's different syntax. And the `dir ^| findstr /c:12345` i was told checked the output of the previous command. and I just realized that it returns the entire line that has the hit for findstr this morning. I'm sorry i couldn't check back here sooner, but this isn't the only thing i have to work on.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a batch file for this, here's an example of how I'd suggest you perform the task:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%cscript.exe"^
 "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /DStatus 2^> NUL^
 ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" "Last 5"^"') Do @For %%I In (%%H
) Do @If /I Not "XXXXX" == "%%I" "%__AppDir__%cscript.exe"^
 "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /UnPKey:%%I
```

All you need to do is to change `XXXXX` on line four to match your actual valid last five product key characters.

*It is actually one line, split into five for readability:*

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /DStatus 2^> NUL ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" "Last 5"^"') Do @For %%I In (%%H) Do @If /I Not "XXXXX" == "%%I" "%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /UnPKey:%%I
```

Comment: **_Please note, the code above will uninstall your Microsoft Office product key, if one exists, and its last five characters do not match the case insensitive string `XXXXX`._** Do not run it without being sure of the repercussions from the outset!

Comment: Does this assume that there's only one key?
Sorry for not being clearer in the OP, but the issue is there's multiple keys active from different versions of previously installed Office. The goal is to uninstall the old keys that don't work while keeping the good keys. there as at least one key, at most 4.

Comment: Yes it assumes one key. It can however be updated/modified, to allow for multiple allowable five character combinations. Have you tried to make those modifications? If so, what did you try? If not, why? _(20 hours is a long time)_.

Comment: because i have other things to do, this batch project is just one thing on my plate. And to be honest, i have only a vague idea of what the above code does.

Comment: @Thomas, my comment directly beneath my answer tells you exactly what it does.

Comment: more specific: I don't know what the `('^""%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /DStatus 2^> NUL ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" "Last 5"^"')` is. Is this the output of the command? what is find.exe, and how has no one told me about it before now, or I stumble upon it trying to find out how this works?

Comment: Yes i realize that's the end output, but it doesn't help me if i don't understand how you got there.

Comment: `"%__AppDir__%cscript.exe"` is the proper full path to `cscript`, _which you were already using_, `"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS"` is the path to the `.vbs` file, _which you were already using_, and `"%__AppDir__%find.exe"` is the proper full path to `find`, as an alternative to `findstr`, _which you were using_.